# Integrating Storybook with Nunjucks (njk)

Tags: storybook, nunjucks, html-templates, eleventy

I am trying to add storybook with my nunjucks project. I am having my components in njk format.
I am getting the below error -

*You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders*

Here is my storybook code -

```
export default {
  title: 'Header',
};

import  Head  from './header.njk';

export const Top = () => {
  return Head;
};
```

As storybook doesn't support nunjucks as per their Github site, i am also looking at the alternatives to the storybook for my nunjucks components.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should setup storybook with custom webpack config, that should contain some webpack loader for nunjucks.

See more in official documentation
https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack